# Validate Anti forgery key not working with ajax post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

[image: added]I have tried to use validate antiforgery token with ajax post request  but the response is that no root element found . 
i remove the antiforgery token it works perfectly .

Here is my code  : 
 javascript  ;

```
  function Save() {
        let GroupName = GetElementValue("GroupName");
        let GroupId = GetElementValue("GroupId");
        var Group = {
            __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
            GroupId: :1",
            GroupName: "My Group Name"
        };

        if (IsFormValid("GroupForm")) {
            AjaxPost("/Groups/AddGroup", Group).done(function () {
                GetGroups();
            });
        }
    }


     function gettoken() {
        var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
        token = $(token).val();
        return token;
   }

function AjaxPost(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        responseType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

I have also tried this   :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Groups/AddGroup",
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
        GroupId: 1,
        GroupName: "please work"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',

});
```

Here Is The backend :

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public void AddGroup([FromBody] GroupView Group)
        {
            if (Group.GroupName.Trim().Length>0)
            {
                bool existed = _context.Groups.Any(x => x.GroupName.ToLower().TrimEnd().Equals(Group.GroupName.ToLower().TrimEnd()));
                if (!existed)
                {
                    Groups group = new Groups()
                    {
                        GroupName = Group.GroupName
                    };
                    _context.Groups.AddAsync(group);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    int? groupId = group.GroupId;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: Here is the parameter passing perfectly]

And Here Is My Class GroupView

```
public class GroupView
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use the method where i send the serial token with my data normally ,
how can i make it works ? 
any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core you can pass antiforgery token either via form or headers. So I can suggest 2 solutions for you.

**Solution 1. Headers**

In order to let the framework read token from headers you need to configure `AntiforgeryOptions` and set `HeaderName` to non `null` value. Add this code to `Startup.cs`

```
//or if you omit this configuration 
//HeaderName will be "RequestVerificationToken" by default
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN"; //may be any other valid header name
});
```

And pass antiforgery token in `AJAX`

```
function Save() {
    //..
    //no need to set token value in group object
    var Group = {
        GroupId: "1",
        GroupName: "My Group Name"
    };
    //..
}

function AjaxPost(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        responseType: "json",
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": gettoken()
        },
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

**Solution 2. Form**

You have already tried to pass token via form but it didn't work. Why? The reason is that the default implementation of `IAntiforgeryTokenStore` (is used for reading tokens from request) cannot read antiforgery token from json but reads it as form data. If you want to make it work then don't `stringify` request data and remove `contentType` property from `$.ajax` call. JQuery will set appropriate content type and serialize data respectively for you.

```
//all other original code is unchanged, group needs to contain a token
function AjaxPost(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        responseType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: data
});
```

Also you need to remove `[FromBody]` attribute from action parameter to let model binder properly bind model in this case

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddGroup(GroupView group)
```

Comment: sending the Antiforgery in header is the best fit for my solution ,

Answer (score 1):

For `FromBody`, it will bind the model from `application/json`, but `CSRF` would not read the token from body.

For the simplest way, you could add the header with `RequestVerificationToken`.

`Controller`

```
[HttpPost("/Groups/AddGroup")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void AddGroup([FromBody] GroupView Group)
{
}
```

`Client`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Group = {
            __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
            GroupId: 1,
            GroupName: "My Group Name"
        };

        AjaxPost("/Groups/AddGroup", Group).done(function () {
            GetGroups();
        });

    });
    function gettoken() {
        var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
        token = $(token).val();
        return token;
    }

    function AjaxPost(url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            responseType: "json",
            url: url,
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": gettoken()
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
</script>
```